# How to disable user from selecting future time from current time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery Mobile to develop a PhoneGap application. I have an input type time. I want to know how to prevent the user from selecting future time from current time. Which means that in the timepicker, the maximum time that I want to allow the user to select is the current time. I have searched in many web pages but all I find are references to datepicker. I cannot find any reference to timepicker. Please suggest or advice me on how can I achieve this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is too broad, you need to be more specific, and add the code you have so far

Comment: currently I have only the jquery timepicker in my html. Thats it. I'm asking a way to manipulate the time that will be displayed in the ui for user selection. For example, current time is 10.00 am. I don't want the user to select 11.00 am. Thats it.

Comment: Add a fiddle :x

Comment: Create a [minimal verifiable and Complete](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<input class="datepicker" />`

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
  minDate: 0,
  maxDate: 0
});
```

Comment: It's For Current Date Select Only

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery datepicker.

```
var endDate = new Date('2012-10-10');
var startDate = new Date('2012-10-05');

$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
   changeYear: true,            
   defaultDate: parsed_date,            
   maxDate: endDate,   
   minDate: startDate,
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kGjdL/1927/)